# Snow Lepord Server (?) - Server Preferances Login (Unable to set node credentials)

Tags: mac-osx-server

Ok, to start with i'm a windows dev, helping a friend out.

He runs a business and has purchased a Mac Server (With Snow Lepord etc) he want to use this as a data store and email distributer (At the moment emails are handeled by POP3 accounts for each user)

As vauge as this sounds, can anyone start by pointing us in the right direction to begin setting this up? Operating system is installed.

Thanks

Edit: When we click on Server Preferances we are prompted for a Server Address, Username and Password? We login using the loopback address and the admin login details. The error message then comes back - Unable to set node credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to look at the [Snow Leopard Server documentation site](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/documentation.html), there are many how too guides include one for file server administration and one for mail server administration.

As for the issue with the preferences panel, is your server joined to a network? If so try using it's actual hostname or IP. If its not, try joining it to the network if possible.

There is a [thread on the apple support](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2163498&tstart=1) forum that seems to match your problem, have you tried any of the solutions here?

Comment: This resolves the first question so thanks. Opening a new question for subsequant issues.